# Filtering posts by WORD in custom field

Tags: custom-field, loop, query-posts

I need to filter my posts in categories pages, by showing only posts that have specific WORD in custom field value. I need php code that i should add in loop for this category.

Details:
I need loop query that will say - show posts in this category (crocs) only if custom field hey 'brand' contain the same value (crocs). BUT note, in custom field 'brand' i have more brands, for example 'diesel, crocs, fendi'. Now i need post to show if value contains crocs, not if it's equal to crocs (as other brands can be present).

Thanks a lot for your help. Maybe this is basic, but I am noob and trying to learn and understand WP :)

Cheers,
  Dean

Comment: could i do something like - show posts if cat_title exist in meta_value???: <?php query_posts('meta_key=Brand&meta_value=*single_cat_title();*');  ?>
 <?php get_template_part( 'loop' , 'entry') ?>

Answer (score 0):

```
args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'brand',
            'value' => 'crocs',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
 );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query